# Simpler way to rewrite this loop

Tags: for-loop, optimization

Is there a simpler way to rewrite this loop? Something with less code.
Any help is appreciated.

```
       for(int i=0; i< 50; i++){
         if(i>=0 && i<10){
            method(arr[0]);
         }
         if(i>=10 && i<20){
         method(arr[1]);
         }
         if(i>=20 && i<30){
         method(arr[2]);
         }
         if(i>=30 && i<40){
         method(arr[3]);
         }
         if(i>=40 && i<50){
         method(arr[4]);
         }

     }
```

Comment: This question would fit better [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this approach:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  int index = i == 0 ? 0 : (int)Math.floor(i / 10);
  method(arr[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite it using the modular function and a counter. This should help reduce the code significantly.

```
int index;
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i< 50; i++){
    index = i%10;
    if(index==0){
        count++;
    }
    method(arr[count-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        method(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

You could use a function to increase readability:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    method10(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was just about writing this first piece of code. I don't like your `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `else`:

```
for (i=0; i<50: i++) {
  if (i<10) {
    method(arr[0]);
  } else if (i<20) {
    method(arr[1]);
  } else if (i<30) {
    method(arr[2]);
  } else if (i<40) {
    method(arr[3]);
  } else {
    method(arr[4]);
  }
}
```

For one liner you can use short if statement. Where the `FALSE` checks another condition

```
for (i=0; i<50: i++) {
  (condition) ? TRUE : FALSE
}
```

Comment: Why not use pattern matching?